# pyspark Run bootstrap parallel

Tags: pyspark, parallel-processing

I have a function that takes 2 spark dataframes, some other arguments and outputs a scalar value.
Would like to bootstrap (to fill missing values in the dataframes above) n times with the whole process above and return the output with n rows.

I tried the below for a simple problem:

```
def sum_fn(a,b):
  return a+b

rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(list(range(1, 9+1)))
df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x,sum_fn(1,x))).toDF()
display(df)
```

This works fine, however when I input my function with sdf as input instead of **sum_fn**
I get an error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 476, in 
   dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", 
  line 72, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 540, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Could someone please suggest on how I could do the same

Thanks

Comment: what is `sdf` you're talking about?

Comment: sorry, spark data frame